# How to change values in column

Tags: python-2.7, csv, data-processing

I have a very large csv which looks like this:

```
"Ion N","Mass","Charge", "X","Y","Z","Azm","Elv","KE" 
80  0.00054858  -1  47.1707 -55  3.72415-180  84.1944   9455.18
112 0.00054858  -1  47.8471 -55 -4.54131  0   87.7457   8762.47
295 0.00054858  -1  46.7803 -55 -6.75611  0   87.0112   8741.07
469 0.00054858  -1  47.0934 -55  4.15287  0   86.4895   8546.51
508 0.00054858  -1  42.581  -55  8.17049  0   83.3024   10586.9
943 0.00054858  -1  50.2317 -55  3.88661  0   81.4794   7712.33
976 0.00054858  -1  53.5885 -55 -13.9906 -180 80.5949   9021.04
988 0.00054858  -1  56.4044 -55 -2.64265  0   86.5792   9331.04
```

I wish to write a program in python which finds and changes the -180 values in the "Azm" column to 0. Could someone please advise on how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

p = pd.read_csv(mycsv)
p.Azm[p['Azm'].astype(str) == '-181'] = 0

p.to_csv('new_csv')
```

This will import your csv, override the appropriate column and write a new csv to your local drive.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However it seems that this method also changes other values in my CSV apart from the targeted "Azm" values of -180. Is there a way I can restrict this to just the "Azm" values?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I've updated my answer, so give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace function to sub out the values in your column.

```
 import pandas as pd

 data = pd.read_csv(my_csv)
 data['Azm'].replace(-180, 0, inplace=True)
 data.to_csv(my_csv)
```

If you end up needing to sub-out other values in this same column, you can make your 'input' and 'replace-with' lists, or provide the fcn with dictionaries to use as substitution pairs

Comment: Thank you for your response.